# Symmetric equations of a line: What happens when the given parallel vector v has a 0 in it?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Background context:
$\mathbf{v} = \langle a, b, c \rangle$ is the given parallel direction vector, $\mathbf{r}_0 = \langle x_0, y_0, z_0 \rangle$ is a point on a line, and symmetric equations in three-space are $\frac{x - x_0}{a} = \frac{y - y_0}{b} = \frac{z - z_0}{c}$

I haven't come across this in any textbook problems, but was extremely curious what would happen if vector $\mathbf{v}$ contained a zero. I'm not extremely advanced in multivariable calculus just yet, but am wondering if this would cause some sort of hole/domain restriction for a given line.
Even if you represented the line in a different form, like in parametric form $( x = x_0 + at )$, if $a = 0$, this would take away $t$, making it so you wouldn't be able to solve for any $x$-coordinates of the line. What does this mean?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Consider the $x$-axis, here $\mathbf{v}=\langle 1,0,0 \rangle$, so $x=t,y=0,z=0$. There's no $t$ in the equations for $y$ and $z$, and that's expected, since they don't change as you walk along the $x$-axis (they are always $0$).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible answers.

One possibility is to say that with a zero the formula as given obviously has a division by zero, which in general is not defined so you get an error.

You could multiply your equation with $abc$ to move all the denominators into numerators. But that might even make things worse: when you have a single zero you suddenly get two terms in the equation both equalling zero even though the corresponding fractions were non-zero, so not a good idea.

Instead of multiplying the whole three-term equation by the common denominator of all, you could perform that cross-multiplication for each pair of fractions.

\begin{align*}
b(x-x_0)&=a(y-y_0)\\
c(x-x_0)&=a(z-z_0)\\
c(y-y_0)&=b(z-z_0)
\end{align*}

You need all three equations, because although usually two of them imply the third, that doesn't hold if the two equations you have are both $0=0$.

You could treat the divisions and the equalities as mere notation, and define your own meaning for that notation. I took that approach in [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474509/35416), explaining how $\frac00$ essentially satisfies all equations while dividing a non-zero number by zero does not. You have to be careful about the lack of transitivity if you do this.

The cleanest setup for this is probably homogeneous coordinates, where scalar multiples are considered equal. So you could rewrite this as

$$[x-x_0:y-y_0:z-z_0]\sim[a:b:c]$$

where the equivalence relationship $\sim$ is defined as

$$[a:b:c]\sim[d:e:f]\quad:\Leftrightarrow\quad \exists\lambda\neq0: (a=\lambda d\wedge b=\lambda e\wedge c=\lambda f)$$

I've actually gone a bit overboard here with notation, switching both from commas to colons to indicate homogenous coordinates, and switching from equality $=$ to equivalence $\sim$. In literature you might find one or the other. Either the notation using square brackets and/or colons already describes equivalence classes, which you can compare using set equality. Or the vectors are regular vectors representing their equivalence classes, and you need the equivalence operation to give them that meaning.

I would think that many people working in that area would intuitively read your equation of fractions as a notational variant for the homogeneous coordinate equivalence, and would thus treat the zeros there quite naturally. And in doing so would violate the wider consensus of forbidding division by zero.